# Tensorflow 1.x Error: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Restoring placeholders

Tags: python, tensorflow, placeholder

This is the error I got:
The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles. For reference, the tensor object was Tensor("x_19:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32) which was passed to the feed with key Tensor("x:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32).

This is my code:

```
self.x_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.x.shape[1]], name='x')
self.t_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.t.shape[1]], name='t')

self.theta = self.net_theta(self.x_tf, self.t_tf)

def net_theta(self, x, t):  
        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('__file__theta.ckpt.meta')
        new_saver.restore(model.sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./')) 
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        x_name = graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")
        t_name = graph.get_tensor_by_name('t:0')
        Pred = graph.get_tensor_by_name('Pred:0')
        feed_dict = {x_name:x,t_name: t}
        theta = self.sess.run(Pred,feed_dict)
        return theta
```

Answer (score 0):

After you launch session as sess, you can use `your_tensor.eval(session=sess)` or `sess.run(your_tensor)` to get you feed tensor into the format of numpy.array and then feed it to your placeholder.

Comment: So x_name and t_name represent my tensors, how would that syntax look? I'm having a bit of trouble implementing the suggestion. Thanks!!

Comment: The problem is that you are passing tensors into your feed dict which is not allowed. What you can do is something like, ```x_name_np = sess.run(x_name)``` and ```t_name_np = sess.run(t_name)```. Then initialize feed_dict like ```feed_dict = {x:x_name_np, t:t_name_np}```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. This is the error I get "InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x' with dtype float and shape [?,1]
  [[{{node x}}]]
  [[x/_101]]
  (1) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x' with dtype float and shape [?,1]
  [[{{node x}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored."

Comment: Are you sure your tensor x_name and t_name are not empty? This error occurs when you pass empty arrays into your feed dict. For a sanity check, try printing them before you pass them into your feed dict

Comment: I'm not sure, it seems like it isn't empty? This is what happened when I printed out x_name, t_name, and pred.Tensor("x:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("t:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Pred:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)

Comment: By the way, the x:0 and t:0 is me recovering 2 numpy values from a previous model I trained.